# Configs loaded in Mule functional tests throw errors, but runs outside of a test

Tags: mule, mule-studio, devkit

I have a strange situation where Mule configs loaded in Mule functional tests throw errors of the sort below from flows with vm's. The annoying thing is this flow runs perfect as a mule application and sometimes by tweaking with mule studio I can get the test to run, almost randomly.

```
<flow name="simpleOutBoundFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="testV"
        name="test" />
    <logger level="ERROR"
        message="blah #[payload]" />
    <foo:outbound config-ref="fooOutbound" doc:name="baa" />
</flow>
```

the error occurs at the vm: line and says something like

> org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 21 in XML document
>   from URL
>   [file:/D:/config.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 21; columnNumber: 18; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'vm:inbound-endpoint'. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)

Any ideas? Really strange one for me.

nb: the  foo:outbound comes from a devKit update site I generated with the maven devkit archtype

Comment: Do you have the namespace for VM declared in your configuration?

Comment: @Seba, yes its there, otherwise when I ran it ass a mule app it would Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when the `mule-transport-vm` JAR is missing from the project classpath. Ensure it is present in the `pom.xml` file with the `provided` scope.

Comment: Thanks mate, you've no idea how much that helps :))

Comment: I'm also finding the same issue(runs as app  but not in Junit test) in non maven projects,  For sample the error **Test.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19 etc etc** is thrown at the config level of the .flow file **<fooConnector:config name="Foo" configFileLocation="properties"  />** can you suggest a solution for that?

Comment: Seems the same issue: missing connector JAR on the classpath (assuming  the`fooConnector` namespace is correctly configured).